# Can you stack dodge modifiers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stacking, armor-class

You can choose the *Combat expertise* feat and the *Dodge* feat. Both of them grant dodge modifiers to Armor Class. Are their Armor Class modifiers stacked?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. The Core Rulebook [has the following to say about dodge bonuses](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Armor%20Class&Category=Combat%20Statistics):

> Dodge Bonuses: Dodge bonuses represent actively avoiding blows. Any situation that denies you your Dexterity bonus also denies you dodge bonuses. (Wearing armor, however, does not limit these bonuses the way it limits a Dexterity bonus to AC.) **Unlike most sorts of bonuses, dodge bonuses stack with each other.**